# Puppeteer headful fails to launch browser when run via cron in local machine, says "Unable to open X display"

Tags: cron, puppeteer, chromium

I have this cron job:

`* * * * * /path/to/node /path/to/script.js >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1`

It's logging the following stack trace:

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[6630:6630:0505/185507.905416:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(1485)] Unable to open X display.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/home/vaibhav/projects/myproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:615:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/home/vaibhav/projects/myproject/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/Launcher.js:606:67)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:215:7)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
script.js
```

It seems like this can be because cron needs `export DISPLAY=:0` to run GUI application (as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/239511/505581)), but adding that has no effect on the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0 1024x768x24' /path/to/node /path/to/script.js` to see if it works.

Note: you may need to `npm install xvfb`.